# Android with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, android

Does Android supports SQL Servers? If so how to connect to SQL 2008 in my Android Application?

Answer (score 2):

You can not connect directly, you need a web service to do the job.

[http.client](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/package-summary.html) can help you with the communication with the web service

Comment: Why not? Shouldn't android support normal libraries for connecting to sql directly over the network? It would be hard to use while moving with the device, but I would think it is possible...

Comment: It is possible, but I am not aware of such libraries

Answer (score 1):

I think i can help you. I have developed a connection from android to Microsoft SQL Server. I've used: web service with Linux Ubuntu, Apache as web server, PHP and FreeTDS to connect Microsoft SQL server, and it works.

I hope it would help you.

http://boedblog.blogspot.com/2012/03/ubuntu-apache-php-freetds-mssql.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jtds driver (version 1.25) to connect to an external sql server - it works!