# Click ListView (Android) items to post into mySQL remote school server

Tags: android, json, phpmyadmin

I have an app that uses Zxing barcode scanner to scan inventory assets (computers, equipment) 
I can return the barcode into a text field. I then can enter more data for that particular scanned asset in other Edit text fields on the form(description, model, serial#). There are buttons down below for saving data to my SQLite DB in a ListView in another activity. I want to know, if I can click on one of the items in the list view and have it's contents sent to mysql server. I've seem some info on the web (google), but does anyone know any good tutorials or walk throughs that can guide me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you would generally run a web service that accepts the data from your app and inserts it into the MySQL database. You could write the web service in any server-side scripting language, but most examples make use of PHP.

For more information, I would suggest looking at these similar questions:

[How to connect to a remote MySQL DB without webservices... ? (ANDROID)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964206/how-to-connect-to-a-remote-mysql-db-without-webservices-android)

[Android remote MySQL operations using a web service with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508439/android-remote-mysql-operations-using-a-web-service-with-php)

Perhaps you would find Kumulos of interest, it's a tool I've been involved in building that allows you to create these kinds of web service and integrate them into your mobile apps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the information... I fell out after I wrote this yesterday.... tired from coding on my app... I got it up and running though... just this last little part... I'm using TeamViewer, and I have some sample php code to use... what I'm trying to see though is how to code it in android, the actual data in my listview activity... thanks for the links... I'll be thoroughly reading through them this evening for a solution...

Comment: Ah ok, sorry for slightly misunderstanding what you're after, good luck finding a solution!

Comment: it's okay... I did find a temporary solution. I added a mysql button with my other save button at the button of my application. I study some coding with json and java and created a json object to hold four elements from my program, wrote my php script and updated my php version on the server side. I then got a good connection and 
"Wa-la", the data posts to the server... just what I wanted... as I learn more over the holidays, I'll add more features...but yeah I completed the app (1.0) for now....

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by passing the selected item to onItemClick based on some code i found online, hope this helps anyone still trying to solve this

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.henga.beverage.JSONParser;



public class Songs extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    TextView ver;
    TextView name;
    TextView api;
    Button Btngetdata;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



    //URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/";

    //JSON Node Names 
    private static final String TAG_OS = "android";
    private static final String TAG_VER = "ver";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_API = "api";

    JSONArray android = null;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



        Btngetdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 new JSONParse().execute();


            }
        });


    }



    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
         private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
             ver = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vers);
             name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
             api = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.api);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Songs.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();



        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }
         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
             pDialog.dismiss();
             try {
                    // Getting JSON Array from URL
                    android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                    for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String api = c.getString(TAG_API);




                    // Adding value HashMap key => value


                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_API, api);

                    oslist.add(map);
                    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);





                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Songs.this, oslist,
                            R.layout.list_songs,
                            new String[] { TAG_VER,TAG_NAME, TAG_API }, new int[] {
                                    R.id.vers,R.id.name, R.id.api});

                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                int position, long id) {
                            //pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            new MyAsyncTask().execute(oslist.get(+position).get("name"));
                            Toast.makeText(Songs.this, "You Clicked on "+oslist.get(+position).get("name"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(Songs.this, Main.class));
                        }
                    });

                    }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


         }
    }
                private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

            @Override
            protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postData(params[0]);
            return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Double result){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Vote sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/z/receiver.php");

            try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }

}
}
```