# Android with SQL Server

Tags: android, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android with SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379237/android-with-sql-server-2008)

Is there a way to use SQL Server with Android Application.

Thanks

Rahul Sharma

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581640/using-an-android-app-to-post-entries-to-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as commenters noted, direct connection is possible with the help of jdts, but this approach is not recommended:

[Why is the paradigm of "Direct Database Connection" not welcomed by Android Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826242/why-is-the-paradigm-of-direct-database-connection-not-welcomed-by-android-platf)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use a WCF web service.

Comment: Note: This is a new feature in vb.net 3.5.  The web service can be easily published to an IIS Server.